# embed an image from sharepoint library in a pdf generated using itextsharp

Tags: sharepoint, itext, xslt, infopath

I have an infopath form which when submitted generates a pdf file with the same form content(XML) using itextsharp library.
I have a node in infopath form that contains the URL of an image from a sharepoint picture library. How do i embed this image into the pdf file generated? Any solution with xslt modification in my xsl file that i am using for transforming the form XML content?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone's actually using InfoPath?  First I've heard.  Wow.  Okay, so there's over 400 questions tagged infopath, but still...

iText's general HTML->PDF functions should convert standard `<img src="...">` tags to PDF just fine.  If that's not an option for some reason, iText's new [XMLWorker](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlworker/) may do the trick, released with 5.1.0.

There's even a demo page up: http://www.lowagie.com/xmlworker

Comment: thanks for the answer...I tried this where src attribute field will have something like - http://server-name/site-name/pic1.bmp, the picture sourced from a sharepoint library. This was not working...then i noticed it was a permission issue. I set full permission for the pic library and now its working :-)